# How to avoid code duplication or multiple iterations?

Tags: c++, oop, code-reuse

Consider the code given below:

```
struct Person{
enum sex{male,female};
int salary;
};

struct PersonSSN:public Person{
int ssn;
};
```

I have a container which contains either Person or PersonSSN only, (known at compile time) sorted in the ascending order of salary value. I have to write a function myfunc() which does the following.

```
void myfunc(){
if the container contains Person:
      print the number of females between two consecutive males.
else if the container contains PersonSSN: 
      print the number of females between two consecutive males 
      and 
      the ssn of the males.
}
```

I have two solutions for this problem but both have some drawbacks.

Solution 1: If I write a function for printing the number of females between males and another function for printing the ssn, I have to iterate through the data twice which is costly.

Solution 2: I can write two classes, `Myfunc`, and `MyfuncSSN` derived from `Myfunc`  and have a virtual function  `process()`. But then the code segment which prints the number females has to be copied from the  `process()` method of the `Myfunc` class into `MyfuncSSN` class. Here code re-use is not there.

What is a better solution?

Comment: `bool sex`?? Which one is `true`? (Why not use an `enum`, would be the real comment.)

Comment: Person **has** SSN. So it's a bad design to design `PersonSSN` as a separate class. Instead SSN should go as member variable for `Person` itself, IMO. Inheritance comes only when there is a **is** relationship between two classes.

Comment: @Mahesh let us assume that the `Person` structure is already there. So you are suggesting that one should modify the `Person` structure to add another data member instead of deriving a new structure? I was thinking that modifying the existing code may not be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about object recognition at compile time, then the answer can be only one - templates. Depending on which kind of container you use it will vary a bit, but if you use std::list it would be

```
#include <list>

template <typename T>
void myfunc(std::list<T>);

template <>
void myfunc(std::list<Person> lst){
    print the number of females between two consecutive males.
}

template <>
void myfunc(std::list<PersonSSN> lst){
    print the number of females between two consecutive males 
    and 
    the ssn of the males.
}
```

EDIT:

if you want to ommit double iteration the only thing i can imagine to do would be to use signgle template function for iterating and printing the number of females between two consecutive males calling another templated function for ssn printing:

```
#include <list>

template <typename T>
void printperson(T p){}

template <>
void printperson(Person p){
    // Do nothing - perhaps you might skip it and use generic implementation instead
}

template <>
void printperson(PersonSSN p){
    print ssn of the person p if it is male.
}

template <typename T>
void myfunc(std::list<T>){
    print the number of females between two consecutive males.
    and while doing so call printperson(list_element);
}
```

This might work for this simple example, but i am sure that for more complicated examples - say you want to print addionally number of males between females for PersonSSN - it might come short, as those two operations (while similar) might turn out to be impossible to separate into part with functionality for different types. Then it will need code doubling or double iteration - don't think there is way around it.

Note: you might (as suggested in comments) switch to const-references in function-args - i am more used to qt-containers which use implicite sharing and therefore dont need it.

Comment: I thought about this solution but this solution requires that I cut and paste the code for `print the number of females between two consecutive males` in both template specializations. Otherwise I have to iterate through the list twice right?

Comment: actually, if the 'print the number of females between two consecutive males' is another templated function, you could avoid duplicating the code. also the example above should probably be passing the lists by const ref :)

Comment: @fileoffset how to write the 'print the number of females between two consecutive males' as another templated function?

Answer (score 0):

This example is so wrong on so many different levels :)

Ideally, "Person" would be a class; "name", "sex" and "SSN" would all be members of the base class, and "process()" would be either a method() or a virtual method().

Q: Is there any chance of changing Person and PersonSSN into classes, and making "process()" a method?

Q: How does your program "know" whether it's got a "Person" record, or a "PersonSSN" record?  Can you make this a parameter into your "process()" function?

**ADDENDUM 9.16.2011**:

The million$ question is "How can your code distinguish between a 'Person' and a 'PersonSSN'?"

If you use a class, you can use "typeof" (unsatisfactory), or you can tie the class-specific behavor to a class method (preferred, and what was suggested with the "template" suggestion).

You also need at least THREE different classes: the "Person" class (which looks and behaves like a person), a "PersonSSN" class (which has the extra data and possibly extra behavior) ... and an "ueber-class" that knows how to COUNT Persons and PersonSSN's.

So yes, I'm suggesting there should be some class that *HAS*, or that *USES* "Persons" and "PersonSSNs".

And yes, you can factor your code that one class uses "Process-count-consecutive", and another calls the parent "Process-count-consecutive", and adds a new "print ssn".

Comment: My actual problem belongs to the domain of object recognition and I cooked up this example to illustrate the issue I am facing hoping that it would convey the idea :) I can convert them into classes. But the `process()` method requires all the `Perosn` or `PersonSSN` objects to be available to get the required answers (counting the number of females between males in the sorted collection). So are you suggesting that the `Person` class should be a container class?